# Lag on the same column pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi I am having solving this problem in pyspark My problem is the column balance is calculated and changes values reccursively.
`if WEEKLY_KPI.First_Emission_Week = Emission_Week balance=Sum_Forecast_Flex  return balance elif Previous_balance is not null  return Previous_Balance  - Sum_Commande_Premiere_Emission = Blance intermediare Si Balance intermédiare > Sum_Forecast_Flex return Balance intermédiare Sinon return Sum_Forecast_Flex` 
I tried using the lag and window functions and it didn't work.

```
# Imports
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit, split,length,when

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkByExamples.com') \
            .getOrCreate()

# prepare Data
:simpleData = (("V533.14619.200.00", "2021S01", 3000,4000,"2021S01"), \
    ("V533.14619.200.00", "2021S02", 1000,3000,"2021S01"),  \
    ("V533.14619.200.00", "2021S03", 3500,4500,"2021S01"),   \
    ("V533.14619.200.01", "2022S03", 3500,4500,"2021S02"),\
    ("V533.14619.200.01", "2022S04", 350,450,"2021S02"),\
    ("V533.14619.200.01", "2022S02", 2200,5000,"2022S02"):
        
   
  )
columns= ["REF", "EMISSION_WEEK", "Sum_Forecast_Flex","Sum_Commande_Premiere_Emission","First_Emission_Week"]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.printSchema()
sdu.show(df)



from pyspark.sql.window import Window
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("REF").orderBy("EMISSION_WEEK")
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag    
df.withColumn("Balance",when(col('EMISSION_WEEK')==col("First_Emission_Week"),col('Sum_Forecast_Flex')) \
              .when((lag("Balance",1).over(windowSpec).isNotNull(),max(((lag("Balance",1).over(windowSpec))-col('Sum_Commande_Premiere_Emission')),col('Sum_Forecast_Flex')))
```

Comment: unable to understand the problem statement. please share the logic you're trying to implement in words within the question.

Comment: My problem is I am calculating the balance  which is a new column and it depends basicaly from the value of the same column just from the previous row